# Issues uploading photos with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm having trouble uploading an image over firebase.
Here's the code:

```
//...
    //Storage
    mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mUserphotos = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("user/@userID");
    mTestphotos = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("user/testPhotos");
//...
    public void uploadImage(Uri uri) {
        Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("user/testPicture"));
        StorageReference testPath = mTestphotos.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
        UploadTask uploadTask = testPath.putFile(file);
        // Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "failure",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
//...
```

To save time yes I am sure the uri is getting the correct photo. There is also more to the uploadImage

Comment: add your logcat here

Comment: Change your failure Toast to show `exception.getMessage()` instead of `failure`, then tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //getting the storage reference
    // filePath  is Uri
    // "uploads/" is STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS
    StorageReference sRef = storageReference.child("uploads/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(filePath));

    //adding the file to reference 
    sRef.putFile(filePath)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    //displaying success toast 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //creating the upload object to store uploaded image details 
                    Upload upload = new Upload(editTextName.getText().toString().trim(), taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());

                    //adding an upload to firebase database 
                    String uploadId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                    mDatabase.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    //displaying the upload progress 
                    double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 Uri uri = data.getData() ;// your image uri 
  StorageReference imagePathReference =   StorageRef.child("Your path");
                    Bitmap bmp = null;
                    try {
                        bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // convert bitmap to byte array to save image in firebase storage
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    if (bmp != null) {
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bos);
                    }
                    byte[] dataNew = bos.toByteArray();

                    uploadTask = imagePathReference.putBytes(dataNew);
                    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            Log.e("firebase ", " addOnFailureListener ");
                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                           // u will  et download url here.
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     private void uploadimage() {
    progressbar.setMessage("Uploading Data");
    progressbar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressbar.show();
    String dateStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(new Date()).toString();
    final StorageReference imagepath = storageReference.child("Image" + dateStamp);
    imagepath.putFile(selectedImage).addOnSuccessListener(
            new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    //Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Image Stored Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    getimage = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    //  bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imagepreview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    Map<String,String> imagemap=new <String,String>HashMap();

                    imagemap.put("imageurl",getimage);

        databaseReference.child(Table_Dashboard).push().setValue(imagemap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                imagepreview.setImageResource(R.mipmap.preview);
                                progressbar.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Image Uploaded Succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

use the above code. it works for me, Hope it will resolve your error